# `\{...}insert` Family of Commands in LaTeX

Tags: floats

The output of `pdflatex --version` is:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

When I enter `pdflatex` and try to add a `topinsert` I get an error, shown below.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
*\topinsert
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \topinsert
```

However, the same code works just fine when parsed using `pdftex`. How do I access the `\{...}insert` family of commands in `pdflatex`?

Comment: `\topinsert` is not LaTeX. Use floats such as `figure` or `table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX uses a different model for floating insertions. The simplistic model of plain TeX allows for just one float per page, be it `\midinsert`, `\topinsert` or `\pageinsert`.

To the contrary, LaTeX allows for more floats on a single page. By default it accepts a maximum of two top floats and one bottom float. The parameters controlling this are `topnumber` and `bottomnumber` (counters), but also `\topfraction` (by default `0.7`, saved in the macro `\topfraction`) and `\bottomfraction` (by default `0.3`, saved in the macro `\bottomfraction`).  It also defines a minimum fraction of the page devoted to text (by default `0.2`, which is saved in the macro `\textfraction`).

The parameters `\topfraction` and `\bottomfraction` control the maximum fraction of the page devoted to top and bottom floats respectively.

The values are examined when the output routine is being performed, so you can change them before a page is shipped out.

Floats can also be declared to be “page floats”, so they'll only go in a dedicated page.

When LaTeX does the analog of `\dosupereject` (in plain TeX parlance), for instance when a chapter is going to start or the endgame routine is invoked, all remaining floats in the queues are inserted as page floats. Note that a page of floats can contain more than one float.

You specify the positioning with characters as optional argument to `\begin{figure}` or `\begin{table}`. The choices are

- `h` for a “here float” (similar to `\midinsert`);
- `t` for a “top float” (similar to `\topinsert`);
- `b` for a “bottom float” (no analog in plain);
- `p` for a “page float” (similar to `\pageinsert`).

You can also add `!` that means “relax a bit the constraints”. Note that LaTeX will *never* do a “page float” on its own initiative, unless forced by a situation where the queues must be flushed (as described above). Similarly to plain TeX `\midinsert`, only specifying `h` will result in `ht` being used. If the optional argument is not used, the default (stored in `\fps@figure` and `\fps@table`) are `tbp` for both figures and tables.

You see you have *much* more than `\topinsert`.